# Can I use more-than-1-year historical data to predict 1-year (or more) default probability?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, econometrics, panel-data, finance

I want to use historical data to predict default probability (PD) of a corporate, says XYZ. I have 4 options, which are described in 4 questions as follows

1. Can I use more-than-1-year historical data (e.g 2 years) to predict 1-year DP of XYZ?
2. Can I use more-than-1-year historical data (e.g 2 years) to predict more-than-1-year DP?
3. Can I use only 1-year historical data to predict only 1-year DP?
4. Can I use only 1-year historical data to predict more-than-1-year DP?

I don't know which options are feasible, which are not. Also, among feasible approaches, which is the best way? Which is the most popular approach in practice?

Any comments, suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!